# break a string in parts

Tags: c#, string

I have a string "pc1|pc2|pc3|"

I want to get each word on different line like:

pc1

pc2

pc3

I need to do this in C#...

any suggestions??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var parts = s.Split(new[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (string word in parts)
{
  Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Comment: Either put a `var` or a `string[]` as variable type of `parts`

Answer (score 12):

```
 string[] parts = s.Split(new [] {'|'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

 foreach (string part in parts)
    Console.WriteLine(part);
```

Comment: and then foreach (string pc in parts) {Console.WriteLine(pc);}

Comment: split should be capitalized "Split"

Comment: Note that with your example, you will get an empty string as the last part, because there is nothing after the last |.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. I added "RemoveEmptyEntries" to avoid the empty part at the end

Comment: This doesn't compile. There is no such overload. Use a char array as the separator parameter.

Answer (score 4):

```
string withNewLines = original.Replace("|", Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "pc1|pc2|pc3|";
string[] words = s.Split('|');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string words[] = string.Split("|");
foreach (string word in words)
{
  Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Comment: your variable is shadowing the built-in not normally a good practice even in throwaway answer code ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
string fullString = "pc1|pc2|pc3|";
foreach (string pc in fullString.Split('|'))
   Console.WriteLine(pc);
```

Comment: split should be capitalized &emdash; "Split"